# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{ \binom{n}{i}} \le [n(2^n -1) ]^{1/2}$ for $n \ge 2$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{ \binom{n}{i}} \le [n(2^n -1) ]^{1/2}$ for $n \ge 2$

What I have tried:

$$2^n -1= \sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}\Rightarrow
 \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{ \binom{n}{i}} \stackrel{?}{\le} \sqrt{n} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}}$$

and I tried using AM-GM inequality, but that just leaves us at $$\frac {\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}}{n} \stackrel{?}\ge \sqrt[n]{ \prod_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}}.$$ How to go about it now? Please give only a hint and not a complete solution of the question.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwartz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{ \binom{n}{i}} \le 
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i} \right)^{1/2}
\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1^2\right)^{1/2}.$$